# How to use Docker in swarm mode for master/slave applications (e.g. MongoDB)

Tags: docker-swarm, master-slave

When using Docker in swarm mode, then accesses to the services are automatically load balanced. This is a problem for applications, which run in master-slave-mode, because they need to access 'exactly' the master, but since the load balancer redirects the traffic, trying to access the master may end up accessing a slave.

Example:
There are two nodes M and S and a service deployed as a Docker stack in swarm mode with two replicas. After deployment, the task running on M becomes the master and the task running on S becomes the slave. 
When the task on S tries to access the task on M, then S will in half of the cases reach M and in the rest access itself.

Direct access only works via the task's network aliases or IP addresses, but since those change on re-deployment (e.g. update of the image), using the aliases/IPs is not an option.

The only solution I have found so far, is to create a service for each node with only a single replica each.
But that kind of defies the purpose of having a swarm, which can automatically distribute the service among the nodes.

Is there any way to disable load balancing for certain services or to create an alias, which can be used to access a task on a specific node?

Comment: I thought that the name of a container could be used as a replacement for IP if all containers are part of the same, user-defined, network.  I'm looking through the documentation for that now.  I know that that works out-of-swarm, but I'm not sure about in-swarm.